# Install CKAN in a sub-directory

Tags: ckan

I have installed CKAN 2.14 in `localhost:8082` and used a proxypass directive in apache to have `www.<domain>.gr/ckan` go to `localhost:8082`.

It works ok except the menu links do not know about the `/ckan` and are produced as `<domain>.gr/dataset` etc, instead of `<domain>.gr/ckan/dataset`.

I have set my `ckan.site_url` correctly but still nothing.

Viewing the body tag from source still says

```html
<body data-site-root="http://<domain>.gr/" data-locale-root="http://<domain>.gr/" >
```

Any ideas of a config setting or a hack in any of the files?

Answer (score 0):

When you set ckan.site_url it only tells CKAN where you've mounted it in apache. It does not determine where it is mounted.

To change where it is mounted, I believe you change the WSGIScriptAlias option in your apache config. e.g. to put CKAN at `/data`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /data /etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi
```

BTW I've added a PR to help avoid this misunderstanding in the CKAN docs slightly better: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2644

Comment: It's been some days now but i think I tried this as well with no luck. I finally asked the server/domain owner to create a new subdomain so I could install CKAN in the root folder